# built audacity on ubuntu, cant launch it

Tags: bash, ubuntu, audacity

I am trying to follow the instructions here ( https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Building_On_Linux ) for building audacity on linux. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'm at the last step, having cloned / built the audacity code, and ran `sudo make install` without an issue. Now I believe audacity is installed on my ubuntu computer, but I can't correctly launch it? There is an audacity program in my software list now, but clicking it launches nothing. The image stays in my dock like the program was started, but no audacity window.

[image]

Is there some other way I can launch audacity from the terminal?

trying to launch the 'portable version' with './audacity' causes an err:

```
$ ./audacity
./audacity: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
martin@martin-HP-Spectre-x360-13-a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have wxWidgets installed on the computer, and it's location needs to be in PATH. For a "portable" app, wxWidgets can be installed anywhere so long as Audacity can find it (see below)

Recent changes in Debian / Ubuntu prevent executables running on double click by default. The best option is to create a launcher, or a shell script to launch the binary.

An example shell script could be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/<path to>/wxWidgets/<build folder>/lib/"
exec ./audacity
```

The file permissions for the shell script need to be set to executable.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop launcher can be fixed to launch Audacity normally from the icon. I had the same problem after building from the same instructions. I modified the desktop launcher's `Exec=` line to add the missing library's path. To find its location(s):

```
cd /
sudo find . -name libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.3
```

I found it in two locations:

`/usr/local/lib/`

`/<path to wxWidgets source directory>/buildgtk/lib/`

Use the system path if it's there so you can delete or move the source as you like. In any case, edit the `audacity.desktop` file to modify the `Exec=` line to add the path:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/audacity.desktop
```

find the line:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 audacity %F
```

and modify it replacing `<path>` below with the path found above:

```
Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path> UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 audacity %F
```

In my case path is `/usr/local/lib/`

Save the changes and the desktop launcher icon should now work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the folder where wxWidgets is installed to the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

If you did all the steps before, just type on Ubuntu:

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
sudo touch audacity.conf
sudo echo /usr/local/lib >> audacity.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score -1):

got it by following these instructions : https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=111755